# Tint and Opacity on swatch do not yield same color on white

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, swatches

On two identical rectangles I use a swatch as fill color. The swatch is C=100, M=0, Y=0, K=0. On one rectangle I've set the Tint for the swatch to 10%, on the Other I've set the opacity to 10%. The result is not the same color on a white background. I'm not sure why this is.

I do understand one makes the rectangle transparent and the other does not, but on a white background I had not expected the difference because the Tint itself would also be calculated based on 0% being whit.

Comment: Indeed a duplicate. Problem is that the artboard blends differently then a white object below would. Adding an opaque white rectangle below the transparent one removes the difference. As does the overprint preview.